# Why LinearLayout looks like this (a white space between elements)?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

This is the basic XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:background="@color/white"
        >
    <!--top part-->
    <include layout="@layout/top" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <!--content area-->
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:background="#ff6600"
            >

    </LinearLayout>

    <!--bottom part-->
    <include layout="@layout/bottom" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

When I load it in the emulator, it looks like on the image below.

[image: Weird display]

What am I doing wrong?

---

**EDIT**

This is top and bottom XML. Basic as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_image"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/bottom"
            />
</LinearLayout>
-----------------------------------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/top_image"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/top"
            />
```

Comment: post your top and bottom Layouts also..

Comment: I've done it! Does it tell anything?

Comment: are you using 9 patch image? try removing `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`

Comment: Tried but it does not help. The only thing that helps is `android:scaleType="fitXY"` but I'd like to do it without it. 9-patch is bottom image, while top is regular png. this is just for testing reasons to see that it behaves the same

Comment: Can you try to add `android:background="#0000ff"` for top and bottom views (in `LinearLayout`)? If white spaces will be blue - it is problem with resizing bottom and top

Comment: there may be problem in 9 patch. and you should go with 9 patch only. otherwise you will have issues across multiple screens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try following

Top.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/top"
    >
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/top_image"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/top"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Bottom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/bottom"
    >
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_image"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/bottom"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and finally Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:background="#000000"
    >
<!--top part-->
<include layout="@layout/top" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<!--content area-->
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ff6600"
        >

</LinearLayout>

<!--bottom part-->
<include layout="@layout/bottom" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This will solve your problem

Comment: I know I can use FitXY and I just wondered if there's another way

Answer (score 1):

remove the `android:layout_weight` from your top and bottom parts (and set it to anything you want, different than 0, in the content area). This way the content will take all the available space.

On what you did, you only told the content to take 5/7 of the available space, which will behave as you show depending on your screen proportions.

Comment: I need layout_weight. It cannot be without it.

Comment: Do your top and bottom drawables have fixed sizes? If so, you put fixed size image into a variable size layout (due to the weight), so that;s the expected behaviour

Comment: actually, the LinearLayout in both top and bottom XML does fill the whole space. It's images that don't. And it's funny as bottom image is 9.png.

Comment: To add: I know I can fix this via attribute `android:scaleType="fitXY"`, but isn't there a way without it

Answer (score 0):

And on a real Smartphone? Is there a space, too?
Have you got the newest Version of the SDK Platform tools?

Answer (score 0):

Check for layout_bottom and layout_top definition. Most probably these layouts have marginTop and marginBottom set.